# Intervention image fail to update in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload

My problem is that all fields are updated, except the image field.
This is my Controller to update the form:

```php
public function update(Meretrice $meretrice, MeretriceRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $meretrice->avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = $meretrice->avatar->getClientOriginalName();
        $save_path = storage_path('app/public') . '/meretrices/id/' . $meretrice->id . '/uploads/images/';
        $path = $save_path . $filename;

        $public_path = '/images/meretrice/' . $meretrice->id . '/avatar/' . $filename;

        File::makeDirectory($save_path, $mode = 0755, true, true);

        Image::make($meretrice->avatar)->save($save_path . $filename);

        $meretrice->avatar = $public_path;
        $meretrice->tags()->sync($request->tags);
        $meretrice->update($request->validated());
    }

    return redirect()->route('meretrice.show', $meretrice)->with('info', 'successfully');
}
```

I use the same code to create and it creates successfully, but to edit I have the problem that not only the image field is updated

Comment: probably `avatar` field isn't in your model fillable object

Comment: @Rakib it is being set directly via `$meretrice->avatar`